# Data Factory config file testing

Tags: azure, configuration, ssis, azure-data-factory

Is there a way to test the config files (LinkedServices) I write for Data Factory. I am looking for something similar to what SSIS has where you create a Data Source, enter your credentials/connection string and then press a button to test that connection. Is something like this possible with Data Factory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand well, you need to check if your Linked Services are able to connect to Source/Destination.

Go to your "Azure Data Factory" and click on Manage

[image]

then click on "Linked services"

[image]

then select one of your "Linked Services"

[image]

For example I selected Azure Data Lake Linked Services here and then we have access to a new page where we can test our connection. You can enter new connection parameters in this page. (Depend of your Linked services you maybe have different page but in all pages you will have test connection button)

[image]

If every things is OK you will have this message if not you will have an error with a message.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After doing a lot of digging I realized there is no such magic button, unfortunately. What you are left with is compiling your code and Publishing to Azure. Then letting it run and if the connection (config) is somehow wrong, Azure will tell you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Copy Wizard in Data Factory Portal, to setup a data source, then there's test connection button, which can be used for the purpose you asked.